# Why does cygstart start my browser as background process?

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin

When I ssh to a Windows 10 machine and open an application using `cygstart` it is started as background processes, i.e. without UI-window. I can't bring the UI to the front because there simply is no UI.

example: `cygstart notepad.exe`

I've tried the arguments `--show` and `--shownormal` but they are beeing ignored.

What do I have to do to open the application with a GUI (so I can use a remote desktop connection to that machine and revise what's going on there. Background-info: I'm using this approach to start UI tests via chromedriver)?

Comment: It is a feature of Windows (from W7 onwards, if I remember right) They blocked GUI access to background process.

Comment: It might work if you Remote Desktop to the server and run the sshd server directly, rather than having it installed as a system service.

Comment: Thx, that must be it. Downside: every automatic system reboot requires a manual remote-desktop login.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late to help but you can use a shell function to hold the application open. I used `cygstart` in bash script to edit a memo using Notepad but I needed a bash function to hold the Cygwin window open until I finished editing in Notepad.

```
cd path\to\memo.txt

cygstart -e memo.txt    # open the memo in Notepad  
holdEditorOpen          # keep Cygwin window open

holdEditorOpen () {
echo -e "   save your memo in Notepad window"
echo -e "               click File, Save"
echo -e "                then File, Exit to close NotePad"
echo -ne "   then in this window, press [Enter] key to proceed ..."
read    # no arg means dump next line of input
}
```

I don't know if this would work for a remote desktop connection but if you still require an answer give this a try.